# Have ul list rows not display when scrolled past top of card-header div

Tags: html, css

I’m having trouble deciding on the best approach for the following behavior:

I have a `div` that acts as a table header, with the class `card-header`. Below it on the same level is a `ul` element that acts as table rows and upon scroll, it is currently overflowing above the table header. I want the rows to not display above the top of the table header (but still partially if needed below the header depending on scroll position). Here is the HTML and CSS I’ve implemented so far for the sticky card-header behavior (needed a seperate `sticky-header` class for the CSS as the `card-header` class is shared across the project, in areas where this functionality isn't desired):

```
<div class="col-12">
  <div class="card card-view list-view messages-ui-card sticky-header">
    <div class="card-header" id="primary_card_header">. . .</div>
    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
      <li class="d-flex list-group-item list-view-item message received selectable unread-received"> . . .</li>
      . . .
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.sticky-header {
    
  .card-header {
    position: sticky;
    top: 94px;
    z-index: 2;
  }
}
```

How can I accomplish this in the most concise manner possible? I'm expecting I'll need to incorporate some JavaScript here, but is there a way via raw CSS? Please let me know if supplemental code snippets or info is needed to help (this is my second ever StackOverflow post), thank you!

**Current Behavior**
[image: Image of current behavior]

Comment: Not exacly sure how you want this to turn out, but have you tried lowering the `top: 94px` so the header sits higher ontop of the `ul`?

Comment: @RamondeVries The image I provided of the current behavior is when the page is in a slightly scrolled state. When scrolled all the way to the top, the header properly sits above the `ul` in a sticky position with the current CSS. All I'm seeking here is a suggestion on how to hide the rows appearing above the header on page scroll.

Comment: maybe `top: 0` on the `.card-header` instead of `94px`. Honestly, without a live demo or at least some actual code we cannot do much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this method. Maybe not the best solution

```
<div class="col-12">
 <div class="card card-view list-view messages-ui-card sticky-header">
 <div class="hidden-top">
  <div class="top-height"></div>
  <div class="card-header" id="primary_card_header">. . .</div>     
 </div>
 
 <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
  <li class="d-flex list-group-item list-view-item message received selectable unread-received"> . . .</li>
  . . .
   </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

and on css:

```
.sticky-header {

.hidden-top{
  z-index: 2;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
 
  .top-height{
     height:40px;
     background-color:#f7f9f9; //same as body background (put dynamic value)
 }
  

.card-header {
  //main navbar with some styling ("Published broadcasts" card css code)
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: This suffices for my needs, thank you very much!